# How to align two TD with different length in same row<tr>

Tags: html, css

Please help me how to align this structure properly. I would like to decrease the size of td "Todays Special" to considerable height. This td grows based on my value say if new fruits added then the header td also grows.
Be kind to help me to resolve this

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td class="title">Todays Special</td>
    <td>
      <div style="height: 120px; width:100%;overflow-y:auto;">
        <table style="height: auto; width:100%;" valign="top">
          <tbody>
            <tr style="vertical-align: baseline;">
              <td colspan="4" class="title">6</td>
              <td colspan="4" class="title">mango</td>
            </tr>
            <tr style="vertical-align: baseline;">
              <td colspan="4" class="title">23</td>
              <td colspan="4" class="title">orange</td>
            </tr>
            <tr style="vertical-align: baseline;">
              <td colspan="4" class="title">29</td>
              <td colspan="4" class="title">banana</td>
            </tr>
            <tr style="vertical-align: baseline;">
              <td colspan="4" class="title">47</td>
              <td colspan="4" class="title">papaya</td>
            </tr>
            <tr style="vertical-align: baseline;">
              <td colspan="4" class="title">11959</td>
              <td colspan="4" class="title">kiwi</td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: This is one of the many down falls of using tables. One option is simply add a vertical align top on the `Todays Special` css so that the text is displayed at the top no matter on tall the other cells get.

Answer (score 0):

If you edit the "Todays Special" td, you can set the desired width and font-size through the style property of the td tag. And also set the alignment you want.
As you are not making a Table header from a row, you have to set different styles to the main td and the rest of the table.
Hope I helped.

Comment: There is no effect even if i can set some width and height  <td style="width:50px;height:20px" rowspan="5">Todays Special</td>. The height is depending on the other column:(

Comment: u need to use width like this `<td class="title" rowspan="5" width="100px">Todays Special</td>`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you just want to match the height of the column **Todays's Special**. You can do this by adding the `rowspan` according to the no. of items in the list

`<td class="title" rowspan="5">Todays Special</td>`

```html
<div>
    <table style="height: auto;" valign="middle">
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td class="title" rowspan="5">Todays Special</td>
                <td class="title">6</td>
                <td class="title">mango</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="title">23</td>
                <td class="title">orange</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="title">29</td>
                <td class="title">banana</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="title">47</td>
                <td class="title">papaya</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="title">11959</td>
                <td >kiwi</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

Comment: The above code again makes the today special column width wide. I want it with small width thou the right id and data columns may grow..Please help me in this

Comment: this is because you have added ` width:100%` in table style so the table adjusts the with of columns according to that you can see the updated answer I removed the ` width:100%` No the width is just the width of the text

Comment: if you want to fix the width of a particular `td` then you can give the width to that `td` like this `<td class="title" rowspan="5" width="100px">Todays Special</td>`. with this you can use `width:100%` in table style it will not affect the width of that column

Comment: <style>
.title{font-family: Verdana,Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;font-size:12px;font-weight:bold;background-color:#DEDEDE;padding-left:5px; padding-top:3px; padding-bottom:3px;
}
</style>

Comment: Please try to apply this style.And i tried alll the suggested option.But the Today Special TD width is equal to all the 5values:(